# Google maps api not always paint the circles

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am making a website that paint several weather stations from file.

The file looks like:

```
{
"estaciones":
[
{"nombre":"Estacion1",
"lon":40.5,
"lat":-3.0,
"valores":{
            "so2":4, 
            "so3":5,
            "co2":3.2
        }
}]
}
```

I try to show a maps circle with longitude and latitude from this "Estacion1" and more with:

```
function imprimir_estacion(estac){
    alert();
    var estacion = new google.maps.Circle({
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(estac.lon,estac.lat),
    radius:20000,
    strokeColor:"#0000FF",
    strokeOpacity:0.8,
    strokeWeight:2,
    fillColor:"#0000FF",
    fillOpacity:0.4
    });
    estacion.setMap(map);
    google.maps.event.addListener(estacion,'click',function() {
        alert(estacion.getCenter());
    });
}
```

The problem is, if I comment the alert() y get only the map, but no the circle.

I try to debug with firebug, but .. there is no error in firebug.

Any help?

[EDIT]

The code used to read the file is:

```
if(navigator.appName.search('Microsoft')>-1) { 
    datos = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP'); 
} else { 
    datos = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
}
leer();
function leer() {
    datos.open('get', 'estaciones.json', true); 
    datos.onreadystatechange= procesar;
    datos.send(null);
}
function procesar() {
    if(datos.readyState==4) {
        my_json = eval('(' + datos.responseText + ')');
        for (var i=0; i < my_json.estaciones.length; i++){
            imprimir_estacion(my_json.estaciones[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks backwards: `center:new google.maps.LatLng(estac.lon,estac.lat),`, probably should be `center:new google.maps.LatLng(estac.lat,estac.lon),` (assuming lon is _supposed_ to be longitude and lat is _supposed to be latitude).

Comment: do you request the file via ajax? When yes, show us how.

Comment: Edit my post to show how I read the file.

Comment: Program in English!!!  Just kidding :)